# Infinite loop with a return statement - bad style but unavoidable?

Tags: language-agnostic, return, infinite-loop

I have an algorithm that will keep running until a test is passed, at which point a value will be returned. The way I am currently implementing it is with an infinite loop, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it without using the infinite loop (to satisfy the purists). The pseudocode is as follows

```
while (true) {
    choose initialNode at random
    G = constructComplicatedGraphFromNode(initialNode)
    if G satisfies some property
        return G
    end
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forgotten do-while? Or `for (;;) { }`. In principle the original form is not bad-style IMHO, as some non-linear behaviour is okay.

```
do {
    choose initialNode at random
    G = constructComplicatedGraphFromNode(initialNode)
} while (! G satisfies some property);
return G
```

Bad style is relying on random picks to terminate the loop however.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to make it a non-infinite loop, changing the while condition.  Something like:

```
var G = default graph
while (G does satisfy property) {
    choose initialNode at random
    G = constructComplicatedGraphFromNode(initialNode)
}
```

If the check on G is long and complicated, you could base the loop on a bool that gets reset if G fulfills the desired condition.

Personally, I would find this a bit cleaner, but I have nothing in particular against a return inside an infinite loop.